# How to set unit for Paint.setTextSize()

Tags: java, android, view

Is it possible to change the unit for `Paint.setTextSize()`? As far as I know, it's pixel but I like to set the text size in DIP for multiple screen support.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Convert it like this

```
// The gesture threshold expressed in dip
private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP = 16.0f;

// Convert the dips to pixels
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
mGestureThreshold = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP * scale + 0.5f);

// Use mGestureThreshold as a distance in pixels
```

from here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels

Comment: another simalar approach that uses a resource file  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5369766/1815624

Comment: How does this even help..?

Answer (score 92):

I know this topic is old and already answered but I would like to also suggest this piece of code:

```
int MY_DIP_VALUE = 5; //5dp

int pixel= (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                              MY_DIP_VALUE, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Textsize should be in SP not in DP

Answer (score 45):

The accepted answer is for gestures, not setting text size. The highest voted answer (at the time of this writing) is close, but the documentation recommends using `sp` rather than `dp` because in addition to being scaled for screen densities (as `dp` values are), `sp` is also scaled according to user preferred font sizes.

**From an `int` in code**

```
int spSize = 17;
float scaledSizeInPixels = spSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
mTextPaint.setTextSize(scaledSizeInPixels);
```

Or alternatively

```
int spSize = 17;
float scaledSizeInPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
        spSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
mTextPaint.setTextSize(scaledSizeInPixels);
```

**From resources**

Or if you have the `sp` or `dp` value in resources:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fontSize">17sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

with

```
float scaledSizeInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fontSize);
mTextPaint.setTextSize(scaledSizeInPixels);
```

**Other links**

- [How to convert DP, PX, SP among each other, especially DP and SP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664993/how-to-convert-dp-px-sp-among-each-other-especially-dp-and-sp)
- [Android: Canvas.drawText() text size on different screen resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368314/android-canvas-drawtext-text-size-on-different-screen-resolutions)
- [`Paint.setTextSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize(float))
- [`getDimensionPixelSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize(int))

Comment: I tested your suggestions but there's the same problem with all of them: E.g. font size 22 looks fine on a Pixel XL (1440x2560, 560dpi) but on a Nexus One (480x800, hdpi=240dpi) it's tiny/not readable anymore. Someone else suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42728414/2016165) but it causes the same thing to happen. It might be best to just use a hardcoded pixel size (e.g. `myPaint.setTextSize(80)`) because this way the text will be the same real-life width (e.g. 0.5") on every device (the canvas scales it!) - even though it obviously won't scale with Android's "font size" setting.

Comment: @Neph, It's been a while since I've worked on this. Does setting the `dp` value to `80` give the same result as using `myPaint.setTextSize(80)`?

Comment: I honestly didn't expect to get an answer after all this time, so thanks for that! You mean, use ` <dimen name="fontSize">17sp</dimen>` with `dp` instead of `sp`? I just tested it with `dp` too but I get the same result for both: `22sp`/`22dp` give me appr. the same result as `myPaint.setTextSize(80)` - at least with the bigger Pixel XL. On the smaller Nexus One the text is way too small to be readable.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what is going on then, but thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 4):

And here is even shorter method to convert dp-s to px-els taking display metrics into account

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize(int)

Answer (score 4):

If your Paint object is being used to draw text on a Canvas, you can let the Canvas handle scaling for you.

When calling [`Canvas.drawText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) the text size is first determined by the passed in `Paint` object, which can be set via [`Paint.setTextSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize(float)). The text size is automatically scaled by `Canvas` based on the canvas density, which can be found using [`Canvas.getDensity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getDensity()).

**When setting the text size on a paint object that will be drawn on Canvas, work with a unit value of `dp` or `sp` and let Canvas handle the scaling for you.**

Comment: In `Paint.setTextSize(float textSize)` the `textSize` is a pixel value. It doesn't seem certain to me that this gets automatically scaled. If it did then I'd think the documentation would say that the units are `sp` or `dp` rather than pixels.

Comment: My app sets a map marker using `Canvas.drawText()`. I tested different solutions but suggestions like `getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fontSize)` don't work properly: `<dimen name="fontSize">22sp</dimen>` looks fine on a Pixel XL (1440x2560, 560dpi), on a Nexus 4 (768x1280, xhdpi=320dpi) it's noticeably smaller but on a Nexus One (480x800, hdpi=240dpi) it's tiny/not readable anymore. `TextView`s are scaled automatically but the canvas handles certain scaling too: It won't react to changes in Android's font settings but it'll ensure that the text is the same size on every device (e.g. 0.5" wide).