# Android: Canvas.drawText() text size on different screen resolutions

Tags: android, text, size, resolution, drawtext

For my Android game I have some calls to `Canvas.drawText()`.

For testing, I use the standard font size which seems to be working fine.

However, when I bump up the resolution to a higher density, the larger images are automatically loaded but the text is now incredibly small.

Is there an easy way to calculate what size the text should be drawn at or am I bound to do this manually?

edit: What was the point of [editing my post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5368314/revisions) @Suragch ?

Comment: Tried using [scaledDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity)?

Comment: Hi Marcin, yep I've used that and the multiplier doesn't seem to do much. As far as I know I'm using the correct multiplying logic also.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The easiest way is to define your font sizes in your resources with the units of scale-independent pixels (`sp`) -- this unit is like density independent pixels (`dp` or `dip`) in that it takes into account the screen density but it also takes into account the font-size setting of the user.

To add a new dimension create a `dimens.xml` file in your `res/values` folder and enter the following code to add a new dimension with the name `myFontSize`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="myFontSize">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You can then get the text size in your application using

```
int scaledSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.myFontSize);
```

The resulting size will be correctly scaled to take into account the current screen density and font-size setting.

For more information see the [Android Developers page on More Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: Interesting method, I'll be sure to try it when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that worked like a charm. I must admit that I was applying it on the wrong Paint object and realised much later. Marcin's solution would of worked fine also.

Comment: Joseph, are you saying ADD R.dimen.font_size and set it to 20sp for example. Then by call this the 20sp will be scaled automagically to whatever screen? Or do we have to add a number of font_size dimensions for each screen res?

Comment: I can't understand why this is not the default behavior.

Comment: a similar approach without a resource file http://stackoverflow.com/a/3062023/1815624

Answer (score 7):

You can do it yourself using a simple math operation:

You need to calculate a relation that draws your text just the same size for any canvas size, so use the actual canvas size, like this:

```
double relation = Math.sqrt(canvas.getWidth() * canvas.getHeight());
```

But that number is just too big, so divide it by one that suits your needs, lets say 250:

```
relation = relation / 250;
```

Now you can set your text size like this:

```
paint.setTextSize((float) (myFontSize * relation));
```

You don't have to necessary divide relation by any number but in that case you will have to use very small font sizes for the variable `myFontSize`. For me 250 works just fine to use regular font sizes that will adjust to any screen size, since you are already taking in count the pixels dimension from your canvas.

Comment: I tested `myPaint.setTextSize(80)` (called before `canvas.drawText`) with different emulators (Nexus One=480x800 up to Nexus XL=1440x2560) and the text was always the same size (e.g. always 1 "real life" cm on the screen). Not sure if this was changed at one point (I'm using Java 8/API 27) but there seems to be no need to compute the size because the canvas automatically scales it accordingly.

Comment: Update: I now tested your suggestion with different emulators and it doesn't give the desired result (anymore?): E.g. font size 22 (with your code) looks fine on a Pixel XL (1440x2560, 560dpi) but on a Nexus One (480x800, hdpi=240dpi) it's tiny/not readable anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to define your font size in your resources directory with the units of `scale-independent pixel (sp)` or the `density-independent pixel (dp)`. Then get the text size using

```
int scaledSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.font_size);
mTextView.setTextSize(scaledSize);
```

This will scale the text-size appropriately according to the current screen density/resolution and the user's font-size setting.

**How to define font size in resource directory?**

Create a file named `dimens.xml` in the folder `res->values`. Then copy the following code.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">25sp</dimen>   // sp or dp accordingly
</resources>
```

The `name` attribute of the tag `<dimen>` will be used as resource ID.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension
i got it.

Answer (score 2):

When calling [`Canvas.drawText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) the text size is first determined by the passed in `Paint` object, which can be set via [`Paint.setTextSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize(float)). The text size is automatically scaled by `Canvas` based on the canvas density, which can be found using [`Canvas.getDensity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getDensity()).

When setting the text size on a paint object that will be drawn on Canvas, work with a unit value of `dp` or `sp` and let Canvas handle the scaling for you.