# How to scale paint text size with screen dimensions?

Tags: android

I've been struggling with this issue for a while:

I'm using canvas to draw text onto the screen, for my Android app. Right now, I'm using this to scale the text size:

```
float scaledTextSize = textSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
paint.setTextSize(scaledTextSize);
```

It does scale a little bit, but doesn't fully keep its "size ratio" compared to the current screen dimensions. I've also tried the method using a dimension from a resource file, but nothing changed.

For example, if I set the text size to be suitable for a Nexus 5 screen, it would be too small for a Nexus 7, and a little bit too big for a Nexus 4.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
double relation = Math.sqrt(canvas.getWidth() * canvas.getHeight()) / 250;
paint.setTextSize((float) (textSize * relation));
```

Answer taken from this thread:
[Android: Canvas.drawText() text size on different screen resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368314/android-canvas-drawtext-text-size-on-different-screen-resolutions)

Answer (score 0):

First convert text size from sp to pixel instead of using dp.

**Scale-independent Pixels** is  used for specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user’s preference.

```
int spSize = 12;//your sp size
  // Convert the sp to pixels
float scaledTextSize = spSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

then set paint setTextSize

```
paint.setTextSize(scaledTextSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried it and didn't seem to work.