# Android: Draw circle of alphabets

Tags: android

I am working in android, I want to draw a circle of Alphabets, in this every alphabets A to Z must show. and this each alphabet must be clickable or touchable.

My view should look like following one:-
[image]

I do not have any idea related to this, how should I start ? please give me some suggestion so I can go ahead.what things should I use to do this.

you may provide me some suitable links.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use the Android [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) API.

Here's an example of drawing text on the Canvas: [Android Canvas.drawText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655402/android-canvas-drawtext) .

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
Paint paint = new Paint();

paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(20); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
```

Just write a loop to iterate where to draw the text and iterate through a-z, like so:

```
for(char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ch++)
{
    System.out.print(ch);
}
```