# Android; TextView does not appear on screen, while my game runs

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

It appears that the actual game is "on top" the textview...

Here's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MyActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I draw everything else onDraw

Comment: `I draw everything else onDraw` Why don't you draw the text in the  `onDraw()` method, too?

Comment: Not enough information available to help find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas.drawText() and delete the TextView. I think that's easier. Look at this for an example: [Android Canvas.drawText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655402/android-canvas-drawtext)