# How to create playstore like shapes

Tags: android

[image: Playstore like shapes]

How to create these download, rating , Media & Video and similar kind of shapes in android ? Is there any library available to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of I know is : [android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) and of course [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) also you can use [floating-action-buttons](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons)

Comment: For media & video you can use floatingactionbutton that is provided by support library. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: do you want this kind of desing or shapes of  icons ?

Comment: I know how to create rectangle and circle. I'm actually looking for some pointers to create the shapes like ratings in this image and also downloads kind of shape.

Comment: It would be great if there is a library available to draw shapes with text

Comment: I think @Yasin Kaçmaz will help you.

Comment: @SaiGaneshPittala if you want to draw both texts and custom shapes you must work with canvas. Canvas have drawText method : [android-canvas-drawtext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655402/android-canvas-drawtext). Also another approach is using a layout with drawing canvas and setting background then add another views to it. Im not home right now but try theese thing and edit your question then so many guys help you much easily with given code

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz will sure try canvas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) library. Its very easy to use.

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.{ClassName}
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siBorderWidth="8dp"
    app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"/>
```

You can put following classes in place of {ClassName}
1. BubbleImageView
2. CircularImageView
3. DiamondImageView
4. HeartImageView
5. HexagonImageView
6. OctogonImageView
7. PentagonImageView
8. RoundedImageView
9. StarImageView
etc